# How to replace the entire row value in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow

Is it possible to replace an entire DataGridViewRow value in one line of code?

```
Dim dgvR As DataGridViewRow = dgvExcelData.Rows(i)
'[...]
Dim row As String() = New String() {a,b,c,d,e}
```

I don't want to replace like this:

```
dgvR.Cells("xxx").Value = a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DataGridViewRow.SetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.setvalues) method.
It accepts an **`object[]`**:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].SetValues(new object[] { 1, "2", 3.01D, DateTime.Now, null });
```

This object array can also be set when the DataGridView is bound to a DataSource.
Make sure the objects in the array correspond to each Cell's [ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.valuetype).

Comment: Is there a way to replace the row values using a class instead of `new object[]`. For instance, assume that we have this `personObj` from the class `PersonDto`, how can we pass it into the `datagridview1`?   
`dataGridView1.Rows[1].SetValues(personObj )` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @rushas You need to implement this functionality in your class object, to achieve a result similar to the `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`  overrides. E.g., add a `ToDataObject()` public method which returns a `new object[]{ }`. This array stores the class's Property values in the order in which they're declared. You can then set the values with, e.g., `[DataGridView].CurrentRow.SetValues([YouClassObject].ToDataObject());`